# Is direct IP packet transfer possible?

Tags: networking, network-protocols, tcp

As far as I know, in order to carry IP packets, we need a link protocol. Is there any exception of this?

Comment: You might want to check out [UDP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol). I don't think it answers your question but it might answer the question behind the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some tunnel protocols can be seen as exceptions. IP tunnels encapsulate an IP packet into another one. At the end a link protocol is needed to carry the resulting packet, but not directly to handle the first one.

You can take a look at IP in IP, 6in4 or 4in6.